# Gnuplot: set size ratio -1 and <lrtb>margin 0 not working?

Tags: pdf-generation, gnuplot, margins

Using Gnuplot, I want to plot a PNG as a background image to a PDF file, which I later would like to plot curves onto. The aspect ratio of the axes should be 1, such that the image is not distorted. Furthermore, there should be no white borders around the image in the PDF file. Currently, I use:

```
set terminal pdf color solid
set output "input.pdf"
unset xtics
unset ytics
unset border
set size ratio -1
set lmargin 0
set rmargin 0
set tmargin 0
set bmargin 0
plot "input.png" binary filetype=png w rgbimage notitle
```

This leaves large white margins at the left and right borders.

When I omit `set size ratio -1`, there are no margins, but the image is distorted.

When I replace `set terminal pdf color solid` with `set terminal pdf color solid size <width>, <height>`, inserting the width and height of the PNG, I get the desired output, i.e. no margins and image retains its original aspect ratio. Unfortunately, in my workflow, this would require parsing and passing these values to Gnuplot automatically, which seems cumbersome.

Is there any reason why setting the margins to 0 does not work together with setting the aspect ratio to 1?

Do you have other solutions that do not require to pass the image dimensions to Gnuplot?

Comment: Yes, the reason is, that the `size` given by the terminal settings is fixed. Within this image size the remaining options apply, which however conflict given the `size` constraints.